# iOS: PDF graphic with transparency causes memory leak

Tags: ios, pdf, uiview, memory-leaks

Working with the code below I can add a pdf vector graphic image to a view. Works well. The problem is when the PDF has transparent or semi transparent graphic elements, this code causes leaks when a graphic is added.

By transparent or semi transparent graphic elements I mean vector paths that are filled with transparent or semitransparent color, as opposed to solid filled paths. or a blank canvas  areas, which causes no leak issues.

```
- (id)initWithPDFResourceAtPath:(NSString *)path center:(CGPoint)center {
    if ((self = [super init])){
        CGPDFPageRelease(pageRef);
        CGPDFDocumentRef documentRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]);
        pageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(documentRef, 1);
        CGPDFPageRetain(pageRef);
        CGPDFDocumentRelease(documentRef);
        [self setBounds];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setBounds {
    [self setBounds:CGRectApplyAffineTransform(CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pageRef, kCGPDFMediaBox), CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleH, scaleV))];
    size = self.bounds.size;
    [self getPDFimage];
}

-(void)getPDFimage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleH, scaleV);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, pageRef);
    [self setImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: You should release `pageRef` in `dealloc`.

Comment: @omz thanks! did that, does not fix the leak.